# Gtk Toolbar item label next to it

Tags: c, gtk, ubuntu-11.04

How can i add a label next to a toolbar item in GTK+?For instance i want to show a save button and the text "Save" next to it like gedit or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`gtk_action_set_is_important()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkAction.html#gtk-action-set-is-important) if you're using GtkActions, [`gtk_tool_item_set_is_important()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkToolItem.html#gtk-tool-item-set-is-important) if you're using GtkToolItems.

Comment: Cheers!You made my day again!